# Getting varying layout width when provided fixed percentage weight

Tags: android, android-layout

I am seeing varying layout weights though i have specified a fixed layout weight.

From the below code you can see that statusLinearLayout is set with layout_weight to 0.2 and the remaining space by other layout.

I am using the below layout for a Recycler item.

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:id="@+id/statusLinearLayout">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/statusTextView" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.8">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/pNameTextView" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/hNameTextView" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/sTypeTextView" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/dateTextView" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainLinearLayout"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the UI what i am getting in emulator:
[image]

How to my statusLinearLayout to have a fixed length than variable lengths?

Comment: Try with android:layout_width="0dp" instead wrap_content for both LinearLayouts

Comment: in both linearlayout layout when you put weight in that width must be ''0dp''

Comment: Thanks everyone, that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/statusLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/statusTextView"
                android:text="nilesh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pNameTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="nilesh"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hNameTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="nilesh"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sTypeTextView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:text="nilesh"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="nilesh"
                    android:gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**RESULT**

[image]